# Cannot install php-mysqli extension on Centos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, centos

I'm trying to install mysqli extension to php

```
yum install php-mysqli
```

And I'm getting the next error

```
...
     Transaction Check Error:
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.34-2.cp1136.x86_64
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.34-2.cp1136.x86_64
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.34-2.cp1136.x86_64
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.34-2.cp1136.x86_64
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL55-server-5.5.34-2.cp1136.x86_64
          file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.71-

...
```

(the log continues)

mysqli package is not installed as I can check with

```
php -m | grep mysqli
```

It returns nothing...

Comment: Resolve the conflict.

Comment: Upgrade your MySQL server to 5.5. Or find a distro for mysqli on 5.1

Comment: Upgrading the server won't cause troubles on my current installation? I'm looking for a way to upgrade the client I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've recompiled apache using EasyApache in WHM, selecting the option MySQLi in "exhaustive options list"

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on Centos 6.4 with WHM and EasyApache 3

Answer (score 5):

CentOS 6.5 64 bit

1- locate mysqli

`/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so`

2- edit php.ini add

`extension=pathroyourfile`

3- restart apache

Comment: First I had to install php-mysqli - then mysqli.so was found on the server running sudo find / -name mysqli*  2>/dev/null

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for any one who may have  the same issue with php7 and no mysqli!

1. go to EasyApache 4 in whm
2. then try to customize (or recompile) a new package
3. choose php versions you want (u can choose multiple)
4. Go to the step called "PHP EXTENSIONS"
5. (THIS IS THE INTERESTING PART) search for php-mysqlnd from the top search field, it may find a couple but don't be fooled if you see one is already installed, shoose the others depending on your php versions in my case I selected all available 4 of them including this one ea-php71-php-mysqlnd.
6. now the last step is to review, build or what ever it is called!

if you get update errors like this :
Update Error: Error: ea-apache24-mod_cgi conflicts with ea-apache24-mod_cgid-2.4.23-2.2.2.cpanel.x86_64

Solution : run this command from root:
yum remove ea-php54-php ea-php54-php-debuginfo ea-php55-php ea-php55-php-debuginfo